# Where is the Php source code for generating the unique session sequence?

Tags: php, mod-lua

I've not found any session handling with mod_lua.
So I guess I'll have to write my own session handler.
Note: that's great because Php lacks of handling timeouts *by values*, it only handles timeout for the whole session.

I'm just looking for the source code of Php where it generates the unique number of the session, to make it with mod_lua.

I've downloaded the whole Php code source but... I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use r.log_id to get a unique number?
or something like:

```
local session_id = r:getcookie("lua_sessionid")
if not session_id then 
    session_id = r:sha1(r.log_id .. r.clock())
    r:setcookie{
        key = "lua_sessionid",
        value = session_id
    }
end
```

Alternately, see http://modlua.org/recipes/cookies for how to work with cookies and unique IDs.

Comment: Thank you very much this was the answer i was looking for.

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I have to use `Logging Functions` so that there will be something like an id or whatever that is created. As long as I dont log something, `log_id` is `nil`... and as long as nothing is written, `log_id` is `nil` (I thought I could fake something like `r.trace8('test')` but it's not written so `log_id` stays `nil`)...

Answer (score 0):

The code for generating PHP session ids is in php_session_create_id, which is available for anyone to view at https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0021095c40a2c2d3d95398c48ae83a06f1381f71/ext/session/session.c#L284